# Return specific value from function

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

I want to return a specific variable from a function, but this variable is unused, so for example:

```
fx <- function(x) { z <- 39  }
```

I tried it with the get function but i didnt get the value, maybe there is an easier solution to this.
How can I return ´z` from this function?

Answer (score 2):

Normally one does not want to directly inject variables into the caller but rather we prefer to return it as the value of the function but assuming you really need this:

```
fx <- function(envir = parent.frame()) invisible(assign("z", 39, envir))

fx()
z
## [1] 39
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear to me what you want to do.  If you want to add the variable `z` with a value to the global environment, using a function, the `<<-` operator does that.  E.g.

```
fx <- function(x){(z <<- x)}
fx(39)
[1] 39
```

With the variable `z` created in the global environment with the value of 39.  However using the `<<-` operator inside of a function is not recommended. Rather assign a global variable to the return value of the function.  E.g.:

```
fx <- function(x){(retVal <- x)}
z <- fx(39)
z
[1] 39
```

Comment: Note that fx as defined in this answer will not necessarily place z into the caller in the case that fx is called from another function.